# Grandpa loves to travel. Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa is in great shape. He loves to travel.

> Grandpa likes Greenwich US  but not NY US
>
> Grandpa likes Harrow UK  but not Darmstadt Germany
>
> Grandpa likes Pune India but not Toronto Canada

Why is that?

Hint

> All towns/cities mentioned had something specific related to them

Hint 2

> Grandpa is in great shape, He is physically fit.

Comment: Does "NY US" refer to the state or the city?

Comment: Both may be true in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grandpa likes Greenwich US

> [Racquetball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racquetball) was invented in Greenwich, CT, by Joe Sobek who printed the rules there in 1952.

Grandpa likes Harrow UK

> [Squash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squash_(sport)) was invented in Harrow School, UK, out of the older game rackets around 1830.

Grandpa likes Pune India

> [Badminton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badminton) was popular in Pune, India, where the rules for the game were drawn up in 1873.

Hints:  All places have something related to them. Grandpa is in great shape, He is physically fit.

> Grandpa likes places where racket sports were codified/invented.

Taking a swing at the three places Grandpa doesn't like thanks to Deem:

> Grandpa keeps shape and avoids board games. Tries below but I'm  unsure of the exact ones.

New York

> Scrabble was invented by Alfred Mosher Butts who was resident in Jackson Heights, New York, and it was there that the game of Scrabble was invented. To memorialize Butts's importance to the invention of the game, there is a street sign at 35th Avenue and 81st Street in Jackson Heights, with their values in Scrabble as a subscript. Butts studied the front page of The New York Times to calculate how frequently each letter of the alphabet was used. He then used each letter's frequency to determine how many of each letter he would include in the game. He included only four "S" tiles so that plurals would not make the game too easy.

Darmstadt

> The Settlers of Catan. Its popularity in the US has gotten it dubbed “The board game of our time” by The Washington Post. It also featured in the 2012 American documentary film titled Going Cardboard, which details the game’s impact on American gaming communities.It was created by Klaus Teuber who was working as a dental technician outside Darmstadt, Germany.

Toronto

> Bakugan Battle Brawler and Balderdash were both developed in Toronto.  Also Tabletop hockey was first designed by Toronto’s Donald H. Munro in 1933 - but perhaps Grandpa likes this.

Comment: Try Board Games. He does not like to sit at home and play board games!

Comment: How about Scrabble @Tom?

Answer (score 15):

This is a super stretch, but

> Does Grandpa dislike travelling to countries' former capital cities?

This is because

> New York was the Capital of the US from 1789-1790;

Also,

> Darmstadt was the Capital of the Grand Duchy of Hesse and the People's State of Hesse;

And finally,

> Toronto was the Capital of the United Province of Canada for part of the 1840s-1850s.

To the best of my knowledge,

> Greenwich (not sure which one, NY or CT), Harrow, and Pune have never been capital cities of sovereign nations.

Comment: Grandpa is in great shape...perhaps that was an indicator that you, too, would have to stretch to reach the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Not to over-post, but could it also be that Grandpa will only like traveling to a city if:

> there are two different vowels in the name?

Explanation:

> **Greenwich** has 2 different vowels (e,i), **Harrow** has 2 (a,o), and **Pune** has 2 (u,e). Meanwhile, **NY** has either 0 or 1 (if you count Y), **Darmstadt** has 1 (a), and **Toronto** has 1 (o).

This would also explain...

> the fact that you said "NY" instead of "New York", which has multiple vowels

Comment: If the name of the country is taken into account, the second entry at least would seem to conflict with this.

Answer (score 2):

This may be off, but does Grandpa like travelling to...

> towns, but not cities?

Greenwich, Harrow UK, and Pune appear to be...

> towns, yet some sources cite Pune as a city.

Meanwhile, NY, Darmstadt, and Toronto are all...

> cities.

Comment: Great answer! This is what I thought of originally, but I've seen that rot13(jvgu n cbchyngvba bire guerr zvyyvba, vg'f gur avagu ynetrfg pvgl va Vaqvn (naq nyfb ovttre guna obgu Gbebagb naq Qnezfgnqg)!)

Comment: PUNE is a big city in India

Answer (score 2):

Does Grandpa like to visit

> towns with double letters in their name?
> Greenwich, Harrow and Pune (formerly known as Poona)

Answer (score 0):

Does Grandpa only like seeing...

> Places where only one letter recurs?

As

> Only "e" repeats in Gr**ee**nwich US, and no letter recurs in NY US. 
>  Only "r" repeats in Ha**rr**ow UK, and "a", "m", "r", "d", "t" recur
>  in **Darm**s**tadt** Ge**rma**ny.  Only "n" repeats in Pune India, and
>  "t", "o", "n", "a" recur in **To**r**onto** C**ana**d**a**.